# How to apply the coordinate limits to one layer only in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

### Data

The data files are not short enough for the question. You can download them [here](https://uwin365-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/durraniu_uwindsor_ca/EueKbo-_TYJIiRIr0zwSc-kBuvUxS0v14XIk4NEghBkOkw?e=c1zMHf).

### Problem

I have 2 datasets. The first one is the `pos_df` which contains the coordinates of vehicle motion as follows:

```
> head(pos_df)
  frames    ED_x      ED_y
1   1442 31367.9 -3103.045
2   1443 31367.9 -3103.045
3   1444 31367.9 -3103.043
4   1445 31367.9 -3103.041
5   1446 31367.9 -3103.038
6   1447 31367.9 -3103.034
```

I can plot it:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() + 
  geom_path(data = pos_df, mapping = aes(ED_x, ED_y))
```

[image]

The second dataset is actually a svg image, `Springfield.svg`. I can read it using the `svgparser` package:

```
# remotes::install_github('coolbutuseless/svgparser')
library(svgparser)
df <- svgparser::read_svg("Springfield.svg", obj_type = 'data.frame')
```

I can plot it as well:

```
ggplot() + 
 geom_path(data = df,
            aes(x, y,
                group = interaction(elem_idx, path_idx)),
            color = "grey50")
```

[image]

**But it is upside down**. Zooming in to the section where `pos_df` is relevant and rotating the plot:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_path(data = df,
            aes(x, y,
                group = interaction(elem_idx, path_idx)),
            color = "grey50") +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(30000, 44000),
                  ylim = c(5000, -7000))
```

[image]

I want to now combine the two datasets. But when I do, the `pos_df` is also flipped:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_path(data = df,
            aes(x, y,
                group = interaction(elem_idx, path_idx)),
            color = "grey50") +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(30000, 44000),
                  ylim = c(5000, -7000)) +
  geom_path(data = pos_df, mapping = aes(ED_x, ED_y), color = "red")+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

How can apply the coord limits to the `df` only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple solution is to use `-ED_y`:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_path(data = df,
            aes(x, y,
                group = interaction(elem_idx, path_idx)),
            color = "grey50") +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(30000, 44000),
                  ylim = c(5000, -7000)) +
  geom_path(data = pos_df, mapping = aes(ED_x, -ED_y), color = "red")+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This solves the issue. But I am still wondering how to apply the coord limits to one layer only.

Comment: @umairdurrani, I don't know how to set limits to a specific layer, and I'm not sure `ggplot2` is designed for this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/3101876/13513328